# how to access and print values from multiple associative arrays?

Tags: php, post, associative-array

I have 2 associative arrays, “drinks” and “snacks”.
Each is displayed in a form as a dropdown/select list, and once a choice is made a user clicks the submit button.  This code seems to work ok.  (Shown under)

```
// create an an associative array for drinks & snacks
$drinks=array("Water"=>2, "Tea"=>3, "Coffee"=>4);
$snacks=array("Nuts"=>4, "Chips"=>3, "Crackers"=>2);

// initialise variables
$drinksCost = 0;
$snacksCost = 0;
$sum = 0;
?>

<!-- create a dropdown form & submit button -->
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])?>" method="POST">
    <h4>Drinks</h4>     
    <select>
    <?php   
        foreach($drinks as $key => $value) {
            echo '<option value ="'.$key. '">' .$key. '</option>';
        }   
    ?>  
    </select>   

    <h4>Snacks</h4>     
    <select>
    <?php   
        foreach($snacks as $key => $value) {
            echo '<option value ="'.$key. '">' .$key. '</option>';
        }   
    ?>  
    </select>   

    <br><br>
    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'>
</form>
```

I’m having a problem with the next step in that I need to:

1. display the selected item from each array, as well as its price (so I should have one drinks item and one snacks item); and then
2. add both prices and display the total sum.

The problem code is underneath and this just prints out every item and then adds the price of the last items in each array.  I would be very grateful for any help!

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        foreach ($drinks as $key => $value){
            $drinksCost = $value;
            echo "<br>Drink order: ".$key .". Cost: $" .$value ."<br>";
        }

        foreach ($snacks as $key => $value){
            $snacksCost = $value;
            echo "<br>Drink order: ".$key .". Cost: $" .$value ."<br>";
        }

        $sum = $drinksCost + $snacksCost;

        echo "<br>Total Cost is: $ " .$sum;
    }
?>
```

Comment: name attribute is must

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Name attribute must . unless your input values not posting to destination page

```
<select name="drinks">
<?php   
    foreach($drinks as $key => $value) {
        echo '<option value ="'.$key. '">' .$key. '</option>';
    }   
?>  
</select>
```

2) No need foreach just access the values directly using post value as a key .like this `$drinks[$_POST['drinks']];`

```
    <?php

    $drinks=array("Water"=>2, "Tea"=>3, "Coffee"=>4);
    $snacks=array("Nuts"=>4, "Chips"=>3, "Crackers"=>2);

        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

            $total =0;
            if(isset($_POST['drinks']) && !empty($_POST['drinks'])){

                $drinksCost = $drinks[$_POST['drinks']];

                $total+= $drinksCost;
                echo "<br>Drink order: ".$_POST['drinks'] .". Cost: $" .$_POST['drinks'] ."<br>";
            }

           if(isset($_POST['snacks']) && !empty($_POST['snacks'])){

                $snacksCost = $snacks[$_POST['snacks']];
               $total+= $snacksCost ;
                echo "<br>snacks order: ".$_POST['snacks'] .". Cost: $" .$_POST['snacks'] ."<br>";
            }

            echo "<br>Total Cost is: $ " .$total;
       }

    ?>
```

Comment: Thanks!  That worked...but in the echo statement I had to insert .$drinkCost (& same for snacks) as follows:   echo "<br>Drink order: ".$_POST['drinks'] .". Cost: $" .$drinksCost ."<br>";

Comment: change the variable like this echo "<br>snacks order: ".$_POST['snacks'] .". Cost: $" .$snacksCost."<br>";

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
$sum = 0;

        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

            foreach ($drinks as $key => $value){
                $drinksCost = $value;
$sum += $drinksCost;
                echo "<br>Drink order: ".$key .". Cost: $" .$value ."<br>";
            }

            foreach ($snacks as $key => $value){
                $snacksCost = $value;
$sum += $drinksCost;
                echo "<br>Drink order: ".$key .". Cost: $" .$value ."<br>";
            }

            echo "<br>Total Cost is: $ " .$sum;
        }
    ?>
```